# Find video content with Facebook Search - US only? How to enable this feature in Europe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-videos

A coworker from USA told me about a new search feature in Facebook. You can find user's uploaded videos. I searched the internet for an announcement in blogs/press but was not lucky.

I am in Europe and changed in settings to `English/US`. How to enable that feature? I can't search for videos.

Is there something like a beta channel I can subscribe and receive latest features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a new feature unless I'm missing an announcement somewhere.

You can just use https://www.facebook.com/search/USERIDHERE/videos-uploaded

or in search phrase format "Videos uploaded by NameofUser"

e.g. https://www.facebook.com/search/4/videos-uploaded

"Videos uploaded by Mark Zuckerberg"